# How can I delete a column by index from a kdb table?

Tags: kdb

For example how would you delete the first column from the following table:

```
q)t: ([] a: (2018.09.25; 2018.09.25; 2018.09.25); b: `ABC`XYZ`BAC ; c: (10 20 30))
q)t
a          b   c
-----------------
2018.09.25 ABC 10
2018.09.25 XYZ 20
2018.09.25 BAC 30
```

The expected result:

```
b   c
---------
ABC 10
XYZ 20
BAC 30
```

It is possible to use `delete a from t` but I would like to be able to delete without knowing the exact column name beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a functional delete:

```
q){[t;index]![t;();0b;enlist cols[t]index]}[t;0]
b   c 
------
ABC 10
XYZ 20
BAC 30
```

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/funsql/#delete

Use parse in order to see what the q-sql statement looks like in functional form:

```
q)parse"delete a from t"
!
`t
()
0b
,,`a
```

Comment: If you join an empty list onto the indices it will work for both atomic or list arguments, instead of using `enlist`, e.g. `{[t;index]![t;();0b;cols[t] (),index]}[t;0]` or `{[t;index]![t;();0b;(),cols[t](),index]}[t;0 1]`

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
{(_/[cols x;desc y])#x}[t;0 2]
```

This takes in the columns of your table, takes the indices you want to drop and uses a drop scan to drop these columns. If you wanted to remove only one index, you'd have to enlist, like so:

```
{(_/[cols x;desc y])#x}[t;enlist 0]
```

Comment: If you join an empty list onto the indices it will work for both atomic or list arguments. `{(_/[cols x;desc (),y])#x}[t;1]` or `{(_/[cols x;desc (),y])#x}[t;0 1]`

Answer (score 3):

If your table is not keyed then you can do simple deletion from dictionary:

```
 q) f:{[t;ind] enlist[cols[t] ind]_t}
 q) f[t;0] 
 b   c 
 ------
 ABC 10
 XYZ 20
 BAC 30
```

Comment: Nice - if you change this to `((),cols[t]ind)_t` it will also work for more than one index

Answer (score 1):

Using `flip` and `drop` :

```
q)flip 1_flip 0!t
b   c
------
ABC 10
XYZ 20
BAC 30
```